# Android Home screen design with tiles type navigation instead of navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-xml

I have an app with home page showing a Google map with current location.

[image]

So according to the sketch in my home page i have a image icon or button type in my first screen and when i click on that icon or button a tile type opens up where there will multiple activities you can go.

Example if you click on 1 then it goes to one activity to do some task and if you click on 2 then it goes to another activity and similarly for 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 and whenever i click on any of the tiles it should go to particular activity.

I tried searching lot how to achieve this task over Google and thought some experts would me help me out with this in here.

And another point is home screen should not change if you click on icon or button in first image. As i mention in image both screen will be home page with map showing current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it yourself. Set a `RelativeLayout` (in which there are six buttons) in the lower-right corner, and set it's visibility to `View.GONE`, then set another view in the lower-right corner as the button to open the expanded menu. When click on it, set the button to `View.GONE` and the `RelativeLayout` `View.VISIBLE`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So if i do this will i able to show map along with that 6 buttons?

Comment: @MacBookPro Yes, the `RelativeLayout` in the app is on `front` of the view that displays the map.

Comment: Wesley i have achieved this but i am not able to hide RelativeLayout(in which there are six buttons) when clicked outside. Like when i click on map i am not able to hide RelativeLayout. Refer this for more clarity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852471/view-gone-when-clicked-outside-that-view?noredirect=1#comment38591699_24852471